# Problems populating js array with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm trying to list some products in DOM from an js array I populate using Angular's $http.get() function.

The JSON reply from php works fine, I console.log the data and its JSON formatted as how it should be, but Angular does not detect this...

My JS code:

```
var app = angular.module("system", []);
var base = "http://localhost/web";

app.controller("CartController", ['$http', function($http){

    $http.get(base+'/store/getCartProducts').
            success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                this.products = data.products;

            }).
            error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                 console.log("Error: " + data);
            });


    this.remove = function(item){
        var id = item.id;
        var index = this.products.indexOf(item);

        this.products.splice(index,1);
    };


}]);
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<div ng-controller="CartController as cart" >
   <table>
        <tbody>

                <!-- CART ITEMS -->

                <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.products" ng-show="cart.products.length">

                        <td><img class="cart-bot-icon" ng-src="{{item.icon}}" ></td>
                        <td class="cart-product-title">{{item.title}}</td>
                        <td><span class="green-price">{{item.price | currency}}</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href ng-click="cart.remove(item)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-cart-item"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>

                </tr>        
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have tried making a `this.loadProducts` function inside the controller, and calling it on `ng-init` on the div, but it doesnt load them.

I have printed the length of my `products` array, and it shows perfectly.

I have tried initializing `this.products = null` and then populating it by calling this.loadProducts and nothing...

Also tried `$scope.products = []` and `$scope.products = null` and nothing....Out of ideas =/

**EDIT 1:**
    Changed to using `this` instead of `$scope`. When i print out `data` in the success method, I get [object Object], correct JSON object. I also `JSON.stringify(data)` and I get a JSON string with double quotes.

Comment: Why does this have the `PHP` tag? To me this seems like a JS question as no PHP code is involved.

Comment: I see the use of cart.products in the html but not products.  Right?

Comment: @vinayakj I understand the async topic, though I'm trying to use Angular's "magic" of data binding

Comment: @ArthurFrankel Yes, but the way to access the products array is to use our cart object....? not products by itself

Comment: I've tried both using $scope and using this, though to no result...

Comment: @vinayakj it works with a dummy json, the problem rises when I do an async Ajax to populate the array

Comment: Alright, created a Fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/w36h1ynq/     but ofcourse it works here, the problem, like i said, rises when doing an async ajax

Comment: Your error function is empty. Are you sure there are no errors when calling the ajax function?

Comment: Yes, I'm printing out to console, only success method gets executed

Comment: Honestly I'm still confused about the cart.products vs. products. I don't see where you make the connection between cart and products in the code. Can you just change cart.products to products in the html to see if that works?

Comment: @ArthurFrankel I did, I also tried using products by itself, but to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `this.products`. There is no `$scope` when you use the `Controller As` syntax.

For debugging, try the following:

In your `success(function (...) { ... })`, add the line `console.log("Data:", data);`.

Then in your HTML add the line `{{cart.products}}` to see if anything is being bound.

I suspect a display issue with the ng-repeat. I answered a similar question on Friday and the user had the same problem. The response you're getting from the server is likely being interpreted as a string, instead of as an object.

You'll likely have to convert it from string to json: `JSON.parse(data.products);`

And I believe the issue is the JSON returned by your server is not valid. For example, if it's using a single-quote instead of a double-quote, that would be invalid JSON.

Comment: be careful with `this` inside the callback, should store as variable and use `variable.products` in callback

Comment: So, when I print data in success method, I get "success: [object Object]". So its being interpreted as a JSON object, also, when I JSON.stringify(data), I get a JSON string with double quotes...

Comment: The {{cart.products}} does not print anything!

Comment: Also, without JSON.parse(), I do this.products[0].title and I receive the text inside that key. So angular already parses it to JSON

Comment: Right after `app.controller("CartController", ['$http', function($http){`, your next line should be `var vm = this;`. From here, use `vm.products = data.products;`. When you create a function, `this` of the controllerAs is overwritten by the `this` of the new function. So the `this.product` inside your `success(...)` is not setting to `scope` of the controller. That's why you have to use a variable like `vm`.

Comment: The same with `var index = this.products.indexOf(item);` and `this.products.splice(index,1);`. Need to change it to `var index = vm.products.indexOf(item);` and `vm.products.splice(index,1);` See the [AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm) section about `controllerAs` for more details.

Comment: Wow....that makes so much sense, and it worked! Thank you man, I'll checkout that link @ngDeveloper